# Why does adding the decorator @lru_cache(from functools) break this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, functools

The function is a part of the solution to the following problem:

"Find all valid combinations of k numbers that sum up to n such that the following conditions are true:

Only numbers 1 through 9 are used.
Each number is used at most once.

Return a list of all possible valid combinations. The list must not contain the same combination twice, and the combinations may be returned in any order."

An example test case which fails with the code:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def CombSum(k,n,num):
    if k<=0 or n<=0 or num>9:
        return []
    if k==1 and n>=num and n<=9:
        return [[n]]
    ans=[]
    while num <= 9:
        for arr in CombSum(k-1,n-num,num+1):
            arr.append(num)
            ans.append(arr)
        num+=1
    return ans
print(CombSum(4,16,1))
```

produces

```
[[9, 4, 2, 1], [8, 5, 2, 1], [7, 6, 2, 1], [8, 4, 3, 1], [7, 5, 3, 1], [6, 5, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2], [7, 4, 3, 2], [6, 5, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2]]
```

The above result is incorrect and when I remove the decorator below, everything works fine:

```
import functools

def CombSum(k,n,num):
    if k<=0 or n<=0 or num>9:
        return []
    if k==1 and n>=num and n<=9:
        return [[n]]
    ans=[]
    while num <= 9:
        for arr in CombSum(k-1,n-num,num+1):
            arr.append(num)
            ans.append(arr)
        num+=1
    return ans
print(CombSum(4,16,1))
```

produces

```
[[9, 4, 2, 1], [8, 5, 2, 1], [7, 6, 2, 1], [8, 4, 3, 1], [7, 5, 3, 1], [6, 5, 4, 1], [7, 4, 3, 2], [6, 5, 3, 2]]
```

This is the correct answer.

Why is the decorator breaking the function?

Comment: maybe because you are returning a mutable object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You violated the decorator’s contract.
You’re mutating elements of the returned list.
The decorator should only be applied to Pure functions.

You defined a Public API that returns a list of lists.
Switch to returning an immutable tuple of tuples.
Then your approach will be compatible with the LRU decorator.

Comment: What's the decorator’s contract?

Comment: @KellyBundy, I thought it was [fairly clear](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache): "_the LRU cache should only be used when you want to reuse previously computed values. Accordingly, it doesn’t make sense to cache functions with side-effects_" The recursive aspect goes against "_previously computed_", since we keep mutating before the final `return`.

Comment: Hmm, "value" could be the list object, and I can imagine situations where it's fine and correct to modify it (for example memoizing a function `list_of_anagrams_seen_so_far(word: str) -> list[str]`). I wouldn't call that a contract / violation.

Comment: @KellyBundy, The docs go on to stress that caller should avoid "_impure functions_". Reaching in to alter the cached value is what lead to OP's POLA violation. Consider a decorated `def dict_of_size(n): return {i: None  for i in range(n)}`. Now consider a caller who does `d = dict_of_size(2); d[2] = "whoops"; assert len(dict_of_size(2)) == 2`. Should caller be surprised when the assertion fails? No. We violated the contract, and get what we deserve. // One can construct examples of Turing machines that exhibit behavior not contemplated by the spec. That's a poor basis to generalize from.

Answer (score 2):

Use a *immutable* object such as a `tuple` and it will work

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def CombSum2(k,n,num):
    if k<=0 or n<=0 or num>9:
        return tuple()
    if k==1 and n>=num and n<=9:
        return (n,),
    ans = tuple()
    while num <= 9:
        for arr in CombSum2(k-1,n-num,num+1):
            arr += num,
            ans += arr,
        num+=1
    return ans
```

Comment: Also, `functools.cache` is available.

Answer (score 2):

Your code also works if you do not modify the list returned by `CombSum(k-1,n-num,num+1)` and make a copy with the new element added instead. Otherwise you are changing the cached result, which makes the return value inconsistent for the same input.

```py
@functools.cache
def CombSum(k,n,num):
    if k<=0 or n<=0 or num>9:
        return []
    if k==1 and n>=num and n<=9:
        return [[n]]
    ans=[]
    while num <= 9:
        for arr in CombSum(k-1,n-num,num+1):
            ans.append(arr + [num])
        num+=1
    return ans
print(CombSum(4,16,1))
```